Why does Sveltekit skip code block that would result in ReferenceError during SSR
By default sveltekit does SSR followed by CSR, so when I try to access window object from the server side I get an error as expected.
<script lang="ts">
  import { browser } from "$app/environment";

  async function hello_world() {
    console.log(`hello world from: ${browser ? "client" : "server"}`);
    console.log(window.localStorage);
    console.log("after accessing localStorage");
  }

  hello_world();
</script>

<p>Hello World!</p>

ReferenceError: window is not defined

However, if I use the await block, then sveltekit seems to magically skip the block of code that would cause the error + all following lines.
<script lang="ts">
  import { browser } from "$app/environment";

  async function hello_world() {
    console.log(`hello world from: ${browser ? "client" : "server"}`);
    console.log(window.localStorage);
    console.log("after accessing localStorage");
  }
</script>

{#await hello_world()}
  <p>Hello World!</p>
{/await}

hello world from: client
<Storage object>
after accessing localStorage

hello world from: server

I was expecting both cases to result in the same ReferenceError, so I would like to understand why and how await causes sveltekit to skip not only the problematic code but also the lines following it.

When SvelteKit do SSR, it will first run your load() function (which is the place where you should run asynchronous operations), and then render your +page.svelte component. After the +page.svelte component has been rendered, the HTML code for it will be sent back, and the component instance will be destroyed, so no {#await} block in the template will have a chance to resolve.
The reason it is like this is because SSR should be fast, and SvelteKit has no way of knowing when the component instance is done with any asynchronous work, so all asynchronous loading in the beginning needs to be in the load() function (which SvelteKit will await), and then the +page.svelte component is expected to be able to render everything it needs directly, and not load anything more on its own.

But you can see that a part of the async function is run (i.e. the console.log). Even if I do a long operation (e.g. for loop 1000 iterations and do console.log) they all get printed. So clearly the await block is waiting for the function to finish? Only after trying to access the window object does the code stop executing.

Hmm... Guess I was too quick this time. @brunnerh, help! xD
